C++ console program read and print text with selectable font and style
I'm going to write a C++ console program that can read my input text and print it with selectable font and style (such as loop rolling and one-by-one print). How can I do that? Thanks for your guys help.
I have no idea lol. The things I only know is input and output text in console, but I can't find a selectable way in changing its font and print style.

I don't think changing the font is a thing that any terminal supports. Some support coloured and bold text, but it's up to the user to define what those actually look like (which is how "themes" work.)

What are "loop rolling" and "one-by-one print", and what do they have to do with fonts?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Sorry for the unclear statement. The loop rolling and one-by-one print are two different style the text shows on terminal. Like the common advertisement board you see on street.

Unfortunately, you have to use some third-party libraries to achieve this function. If you are in a Windows terminal, you can use <windows.h>

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
